# Encoding / decoding performance estimation question of HDVICP2 of TI DM385

Tags: h.264, soc

I am estimating the encoding and decoding performance of HDVICP2 of TI DM385. The SOC is very very old so FAEs just ignored me.

My question is: How to calculate encoding / decoding performance of HDVICP2 encoder / decoder correctly?

For example:

According to "Table 2 Cycle Information" of datasheet "H264 High Profile Decoder 2.0 on HDVICP2 and Media Controller Based Platform Data Sheet (SPRS839)", I can find the average and peak cycles per second of test file "station_p1920x1080_7mbps_IPB_30fps.264" are 155.57 and 160.63 separately.

[image]

If every operation of HDVICP2 takes only one cycle, I can simply say that a 1080p60 video with the same characteristic will take about 2 times cycles per second so the decoder is able to deal with only one 1080p60 video but unable to deal with more 1080p60 video at the same time. (If working frequency is 533MHZ, 155.57*2=311 and smaller than 533)

Is above hypothesis correct? If no, please answer me why. Thanks very much.